# Calculating how many more shares to create

Tags: linear-algebra, finance

1. Shares in company: $3000$
2. Valuation: $\$3$ million
3. Person $A$ $2000$ Shares ($\$2$m in equity)
4. Person $B$ $1000$ Shares ($\$1$m in equity)

If person $C$ came along with $\$1$m and wanted to invest it in the company, what formula would you use to calculate how many more shares should be created to give person $C$ a fair stake in the company. I know that the answer is $1000$ more shares need to be created as that's what person $C$ is entitled to (to give them a $25\%$ stake in the company) - But for the life of me I can't figure out a formula.

What I've got so far is:

$\frac{1m}{1m+3m} = 0.25$  - What their fair share in the company should be after investing.

$0.25 = \frac{x}{3000 + x}$  - $x$ is the number of shares that need to be created, but I can't resolve for $x$ because $x$ is there twice.

Thanks, sorry if this question is dumb.

Comment: Current price per share is $\$1000$ based on $3M \div 3000$.  Net worth of company is changing to $4M$, re C's investment.  You do not want to alter the equity of the pre-existing investors.  Therefore, price per share should remain at $\$1000$.

Comment: The share count has to be altered unfortunately.

Comment: Of course, but the price per share does not have to be altered.  This explains why C receives $1000$ shares for his investment of $\$1M$.  That leaves the ratio of total equity divided by number of shares constant, which means that A and B have their equity unchanged.

Comment: price per share stays at $\$1000$.  Total equity now at $\$4M$.  Therefore, new total number of shares must be $\$4M \div \$1000 = 4000$.  Old number of shares was $3000$.  Therefore, number of shares to be *newly added* is $(4000 - 3000).$

Comment: Thank you good sir/mam, I knew I was doing something silly haha.